# How to mapp Address varibale in Userdao with Address varible in UserDto

Tags: spring, mapper, modelmapper

**I have 4 Java classes As I Describe Below manually creating bean mappers is time-consuming. The library can generate bean mapper classes automatically.**

```
public class UserDao {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<AddressDao> address;
}


public class AddressDao {

    public String city;
    public String Country;
}

public class UserDto {

    private int userID;
    private String userName;
    private List<AddressDto> userAddress;
}

public class AddressDto {

    private String userCity;
    private String userCountry;
}
```

***How to map User Address variables with  UserDto address Variables.***

```
@Mappings({
        @Mapping(source ="id" ,target="userID"),

        @Mapping(source ="name" ,target="userName"),

        @Mapping(source ="userdao.address.city" ,target="userAddress.userCity"),

        @Mapping(source ="userdao.address.country" ,target="userAddress.userCountry")

    })

    public UserDto usertouserDto(UserDao userdao);

    public List<UserDto> usertoUserDtos(List<UserDao> userDao);
```

**This way is not working.**

Answer (score 0):

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {AddressMapper.class})
public interface UserdtoMapper {

```
    @Mapping(source ="id" ,target="userID")
    @Mapping(source ="name" ,target="userName")
    UserDto usertouserDto(UserDao userdao);

    List<UserDto> usertoUserDtos(List<UserDao> userDao);
```

}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface AddressMapper {

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source ="city" ,target="userCity"),
    @Mapping(source ="Country" ,target="userCountry")
})

AddressDto mappingAddressDto(AddressDao addressDao);

List<AddressDto> mappingAddressDto(List<AddressDao> addressDao);
```

}

uses Solves my issue.